# Why won't Sinatra work correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-ec2, sinatra

I was recently trying to set up an Amazon EC2 instance to run Rails and Sinatra apps. The problem - Sinatra won't start. When I try to run the .rb file, it throws something like this:

```
$ ruby hello.rb 
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/sinatra-1.2.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1144:in `define_method': tried to create Proc object without a block (ArgumentError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/sinatra-1.2.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1144:in `compile!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/sinatra-1.2.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1129:in `route'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/sinatra-1.2.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1111:in `get'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/sinatra-1.2.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1474:in `send'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/sinatra-1.2.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1474:in `get'
        from hello.rb:4
```

Now, I initially thought that was something specific to EC2. So I set up RVM on my Mac and tried the same - same result. Then I thought it might be a specific version of Ruby being used (1.9.2). It is not - the problem persists even with 1.8.7. Now, I am completely lost. Here is the list of gems currently installed on my EC2 instance:

```
$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.0.7)
actionpack (3.0.7)
activemodel (3.0.7)
activerecord (3.0.7)
activeresource (3.0.7)
activesupport (3.0.7)
arel (2.0.9)
builder (2.1.2)
bundler (1.0.12)
coderay (0.9.7)
erubis (2.6.6)
i18n (0.5.0)
mail (2.2.19)
method_source (0.4.1)
mime-types (1.16)
polyglot (0.3.1)
pry (0.8.3)
rack (1.2.2)
rack-mount (0.6.14)
rack-test (0.5.7)
rails (3.0.7)
railties (3.0.7)
rainbow (1.1.1)
rake (0.8.7)
ruby_parser (2.0.6)
sexp_processor (3.0.5)
sinatra (1.2.5)
slop (1.5.3)
thor (0.14.6)
tilt (1.3)
treetop (1.4.9)
tzinfo (0.3.27)
```

Please let me know what you think of that - any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you show your `hello.rb` file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error when starting Sinatra: "tried to create Proc object without a block"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845278/error-when-starting-sinatra-tried-to-create-proc-object-without-a-block)

Comment: +1 for having the pry gem installed :)

Comment: There's nothing interesting in the hello.rb file, really. Just the very example from Sinatra website, plus a line requiring rubygems. Yes, it's a dupe indeed. Pry FTW, I even require it in my .irbrc file - great job with that!

Comment: Because this is a Sinatra bug, not related to RVM, I am changing the title and removing the RVM tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's a bug in sinatra: https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/issues/258.

As a workaround, try the previous version of sinatra: `gem install sinatra -v 1.2.3`, either in a new rvm gemset, or specify the version you want in your file with `gem 'sinatra' '=1.2.3'` before your `require sinatra` line.

#### Update:

Sinatra 1.2.5 (the version at fault) [has been yanked and a new version released](http://rubygems.org/gems/sinatra/versions). Anyone getting this error can now just do `gem update sinatra` and use the updated gem.

Comment: Fair play to you matt, this is the very bug you've mentioned. Looks like the newest version of Sinatra gem fixed that alright. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not a RVM problem, as I use it with Sinatra.

Here's some test code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'sinatra'

get '/hi' do
  "Hello World! #{ `rvm -v` }"
end
```

Save that to something like `test.rb` and do a `chmod +x test.rb` to make it executable. Confirm you're running Ruby under RVM's control using `which ruby`, which should return a path in your `~/.rvm` path. Run the code using `./test.rb` and your RVM controlled Ruby will start it.

The console out:

```
>> == Sinatra/1.2.3 has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from WEBrick
>> [2011-04-30 14:49:56] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
>> [2011-04-30 14:49:56] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-02-18) [x86_64-darwin10.6.0]
>> [2011-04-30 14:49:56] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3387 port=4567
>> 127.0.0.1 - - [30/Apr/2011 14:50:02] "GET /hi HTTP/1.1" 200 103 0.2499
>> localhost - - [30/Apr/2011:14:50:01 MST] "GET /hi HTTP/1.1" 200 103
>> - -> /hi
>> 127.0.0.1 - - [30/Apr/2011 14:50:02] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 441 0.0008
>> localhost - - [30/Apr/2011:14:50:02 MST] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 441
>> http://localhost:4567/hi -> /favicon.ico
>> 
>> == Sinatra has ended his set (crowd applauds)
>> [2011-04-30 14:50:11] INFO  going to shutdown ...
>> [2011-04-30 14:50:11] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
```

And what I saw in my browser:

```
Hello World! rvm 1.6.5 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]
```

Changing it to:

```
get '/hi' do
  "<pre>#{ `which ruby` }</pre>"
end
```

displays this in my browser:

```
/Users/greg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby
```

So, basically, I've got RVM running on my system and Ruby 1.9.2 is the current Ruby. Try that code, run it and see if you get output in your browser.

Also see whether your RVM is current. It bumped up to 1.6.5 last week. If you're not current use:

```
rvm get head
rvm reload
```

---

EDIT:

One further test to show which Ruby is running: Change the code to this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'sinatra'

get '/hi' do
  "Running using: #{RUBY_VERSION}<br>Ruby in path found at: #{ `which ruby` }"
end
```

and run it. If your interpreter is running the system-installed Ruby on MacOS or the default install for Ruby via apt-get, you'll be on 1.8.7. I get:

```
Running using: 1.9.2
Ruby in path found at: /Users/greg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby
```

Comment: This does not look quite right. You are running your app using system Ruby by using the shebang in the first line. Then the eval statement is asking the system which Ruby would it use by default and indeed it gives you the RVM version. That has no connection with what is running your app, though. Try requiring a gem which is known to your system Ruby and not to your RVM Ruby and you'll figure out what I mean. Thanks anyway!

Comment: "You are running your app using system Ruby". No, I am using the Ruby defined by my environment, which is demonstrated by the `which ruby` output. That is the way we use alternate versions of Perl and Ruby based on our path, instead of a hardcoded path to a particular version. You're seeing a bug in Sinatra v1.2.5, which I forgot about. I re-installed 1.2.5 and duplicated the problem it. I re-ran into it answering a different question here on SO. Just downgrade your version or use the `gem` command in the other answer which is what I recommended in my other answer.

Comment: I added one more test showing that it's a RVM-based Ruby running the code.