# Error when starting Sinatra: "tried to create Proc object without a block"

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am very new to ruby / rails and have an issue that I have not been able to figure out but feel it should be relatively simple to fix.

**Command:**

```
ruby app.rb
```

**Error:**

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.2.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1144:in `define_method': tried to create Proc object without a block (ArgumentError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.2.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1144:in `compile!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.2.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1129:in `route'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.2.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1111:in `get'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.2.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1474:in `send'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.2.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1474:in `get'
    from app.rb:4
```

**app.rb contents:**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  "Hello World"
end
```

I have updated all gems and still get the same error.  I can post list of gems as well if need.

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with Rails, which is a completely different, "competing" framework to Sinatra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can tell, and I've encountered this before, v1.2.5 of Sinatra is the problem. v1.2.3 doesn't do it, so try

```
gem install sinatra -v 1.2.3
```

to install the previous version, then add:

```
gem 'sinatra', '=1.2.3'
```

before the `require` statement.

[This is documented](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/issues/258) as an issue.

---

EDIT: Sinatra just bumped to a new version, 1.2.6, which fixes this problem. Use `gem update sinatra`, followed by `gem uninstall sinatra -v 1.2.5` to remove the old, buggy, version.

Comment: https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/issues/258 - I've just given pretty much the same answer as this to another question.

Comment: Upgrading to the new 1.2.6 should fix this. (Downgrade no longer appropriate.)

Comment: Thank you Tin Man and Phrogz, these both worked but luckily I am just digging in now when the upgrade is available.  :)