# Trouble deploying a Sinatra application on Heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra

I am new to the Ruby and Heroku world and I am trying to deploy a very basic Sinatra app on heroku.  I have the following files:

config.ru:

```
require './hi'
run Sinatra::Application
```

hi.rb:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  "Hello from Sinatra on Heroku!"
end
```

.gems

```
sinatra
```

When push to heroku and launch the app it crashes with the following entry in the logs:

```
2011-05-03T05:52:02+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.gems/gems/sinatra-1.2.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1144:in `define_method': tried to create Proc object without a block (ArgumentError)
2011-05-03T05:52:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.gems/gems/sinatra-1.2.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1144:in `compile!'
2011-05-03T05:52:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.gems/gems/sinatra-1.2.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1129:in `route'
2011-05-03T05:52:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.gems/gems/sinatra-1.2.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1111:in `get'
2011-05-03T05:52:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.gems/gems/sinatra-1.2.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1474:in `send'
2011-05-03T05:52:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.gems/gems/sinatra-1.2.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1474:in `get'
2011-05-03T05:52:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from ./hi.rb:4
2011-05-03T05:52:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
2011-05-03T05:52:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
2011-05-03T05:52:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:1
2011-05-03T05:52:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:23
2011-05-03T05:52:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.gems/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2011-05-03T05:52:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.gems/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2011-05-03T05:52:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.gems/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:63:in `new'
2011-05-03T05:52:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.gems/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:63:in `map'
2011-05-03T05:52:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:18
2011-05-03T05:52:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.gems/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2011-05-03T05:52:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.gems/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2011-05-03T05:52:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `new'
2011-05-03T05:52:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11
2011-05-03T05:52:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.gems/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2011-05-03T05:52:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.gems/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2011-05-03T05:52:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `new'
2011-05-03T05:52:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1
2011-05-02T22:52:03-07:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Search indicates that 1.2.5 is your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845278/error-when-starting-sinatra-tried-to-create-proc-object-without-a-block

Comment: Thanks! that did the trick.  I had to change my .gems file to this : sinatra --version 1.2.3

Answer (score 3):

Problem was sinatra - they updated it, so now everything running smoothly on 1.2.6.